# Some elements of last column in kable table are bottom justified unexpectedly

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

So I'm creating some tables with Kable that are compiled into a PDF form.  My code is below.

```
 kable(df, "latex", booktabs = T, row.names = FALSE, format = "latex", valign = 't', linesep = "") %>%
        kable_styling(full_width = T, font_size = 14) %>% 
        column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
        add_indent(c(2:7)) %>%
        add_indent(c(3,5,7)) %>%
          row_spec(c(1,3,5,7), background = "TableColorOne") %>%
          row_spec(0, background = "TableColorTwo")
```

Everything runs as normal, but some values in the last column become bottom justified.  This table is generated dynamically so sometimes it has 3 or 4 columns.

[image: 3 column table, 3rd column, row 3 and 5 are bottom justified unexpectedly]
3 column table, 3rd column, row 3 and 5 are bottom justified unexpectedly

[image: 4 column table, 4th column, row 3 and 5 are bottom justified unexpectedly]
4 column table, 4th column, row 3 and 5 are bottom justified unexpectedly

[This](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1487) github issue seems relevant but modifying valign and position do not seem to have any impact on the text placement.

Is there any way that I can stop this unintended bottom justification?

Comment: Please make a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: I'm working on putting an example together!

Comment: What version of LaTeX are you running? What happens when you drop the use of `valign='t'`; don't know whether that points to alignment of the table, or each cell in the table?

Comment: Probably related: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68732/5764)